# Running Vanilla ASP.NET-Core website on windows server get message "Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to run the default vanilla ASP.NET core website from VS, on my windows server 2016 instance.  But when I run it I get a HTTP 502.3 error

[image]

I enabled logging from the web config, the logging message I get back is

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

I've install the windows hosting bundles

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1

[image]

The CSProj is targeting the netcoreapp2.1 runtime

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: Try looking in event viewer for any exceptions etc. Are you trying to run this self hosted or in IIS?

Comment: the default website will try to listen to http/https port 5000 and 5001, do you have already something listening on those ports? I use TCPView to check (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview ).

Comment: Hi @JoeAudette VS is run as administrator but the website has been published and is running on Windows Server 2016 under IIS

Comment: Thanks Matti Price. I checked the event view and found Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/TEST SANKALA.CO.UK' with physical root 'D:\Websites\test.sankala.co.uk\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\Test .NET Core.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005' : 80008091.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default publication was using 'portable' as a target runtime, which requires the SDK to be installed. Switching it to match your machine architecture, 'win-x64' in that case, enables it to run with simply the proper dotnet runtime installed.

Comment: Tried this and it works! Many thanks @Daboul. Who would have thought the default publication was using the 'portable' framework would require the SDK.

Comment: Although I switch to `win-x64` it is still giving the error: `'0x80004005' : 80008091` for my case.

Comment: @ibubi Windows hosting bundles are installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes im on a Windows server with shared IIS and hosting bundles and runtimes all installed.

Answer (score 2):

The hosting bundle is for IIS proper, when deploying an already compiled ASP.NET Core app. In Visual Studio, you're running against IIS Express and the source code needs to be compiled to deploy it there. That requires the SDK; the runtime is not enough. Download the .NET Core SDK and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks Chris. The website has been published and I'm attempting to run this on Windows Server 2016 under IIS.  As far as I'm aware the SDK is not necessary on the production server

Comment: Then can you go in the folder where it is publish and run a simple dotnet run to see what it tells?

Comment: @Daboul tried your suggestion that command gives me the same message as the the 'Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409'

Comment: I don't understand really. When you publish in the folder, you should be able to put that folder on a machine with the proper runtimes and run it without a need for an sdk, I'm doing it all the time. Any particular setting during the publishing phase you would have tweaked?

Comment: @Daboul I've simply used a blank Core.ASP.NET website template in VS 2017 and gone straight to publish to a folder in Release configuration. This folder is then copied to windows server 2016 where it is run under IIS.

Comment: @Hevski you can pick a few parameters when publishing. Your target framework is 'netcoreapp2.1' which should be fine. What about the "deployment mode' and the 'target runtime'? Can you try 'Framlework-Dependent' / 'win-x64' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189138/discussion-between-hevski-and-daboul).